# fetch only numbers side by side in a column without the rest of numbers in it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, numbers, regexp-replace

I've got a string column - name it COLUMN_X - in which there are comments from users about transactions. I need a method to fetch only numbers that are side by side, not the ones which are before/after space, sign or anything.
Now I'm using this solution:
regexp_replace(COLUMN_X, '[^[:digit:]]', '')
and it's almost okay but I've got problem with strings like:
"invoice number 11000222 (E223)" - and in final result it's not "11000222" but "11000222223" and I need it as "11000222", how can I retrieve it like that? And can I exclude from it examples where people type just dates like '04.06.2019' - I don't want to see numbers from it as "04062019' but to omit examples like that.

And extra question is if I can somehow retrieve a invoice number if it's like that:
"invoice number BR/13003/21/2" to retrieve in situations like that just the "BR/13003/21/2"?

I used regexp_replace(COLUMN_X, '[^[:digit:]]', '') and tried to changed it to get results as i want but i don't get what i want and have some problems with this regexp expression

Comment: Your regexp_replace call only removes characters that are not digits.  Please edit your original post to show a variety of data that you are working with in before/after examples.  What if there is more than one set of digits in the string?

Comment: From my point of view, it is difficult to create a single *expression* which will satisfy all cases you mentioned. There seem to be *exceptions* to the rule; for example, strings that follow "invoice number" - how do you (and then Oracle) know that '11000222 (E223)' should return only 11000222, while in 'BR/13003/21/2' the result is all of that? Also, 04.06.2019 - that's a date, it is obvious to you and me - but how will you instruct Oracle that it should be discarded? It contains consecutive digits (04, 06 and 2019) but you still don't want them as result.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a **function** and parse each string, applying number of rules which lead to desired result. Keeping it all in the same (regex?) expression might lead to solution (if any at all) which will be very difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

For the first pattern you could used:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('invoice number 1100022223432 [43] (E223)', '[[:digit:]]+?\s')
  FROM dual;
```